# Can an F1-visa student pursuing masters in US teach in community college?

Tags: masters, teaching, community-college

Is it possible for an international student who is pursuing masters in USA, to teach in a community college after MS as a full time employee? I am interested in teaching and I work as a teaching assistant for undergraduates. I conduct classes to these students thrice a week and I really enjoy the experience. I would like to look for job opportunities in teaching field with a Masters degree. Are community colleges a good shot or are there any other similar opportunities?

Comment: _to teach in a community college after MS as a full time employee_ For how long?

Comment: For about 2-3 years.. Depending on further opportunities.

Comment: [This F-1 OPT page](http://www.uscis.gov/eir/visa-guide/f-1-opt-optional-practical-training/f-1-optional-practical-training-opt) should explain the answer to you.

Answer (score 1):

In the US, F-1 visa holders can apply for an extension called Optional Practical Training (OPT) after their graduation. The default is a 1 year extension, and STEM field graduates have a slightly longer period.

Talk to the people responsible for international student affairs in your school for more details.

Comment: Beyond OPT, you'd need a visa to continue working in such a position.  Most community colleges would be unwilling to pay the costs associated with sponsoring you for an H-1B visa and eventual permanent residency.